# Cloud Speech-to-Text punctuation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm trying to find out how I may punctuate in cloud Cloud Speech-to-Text, not in English, but another language. This is a basic requirement for my use case. I'm sure google has thought of it.

Has anybody experience of this?

Comment: Have you studied this article ... https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation .... what have you tried?  What language are you desiring?  What was the result vs the expected result?

Comment: adding it some manual way I would have thought possible.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, [automatic punctuation is only available for US English only (en-US)](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/supported-features-languages#automatic_punctuation). It is likely that this feature will be available for other languages at some point, but I would recommend you to ask GCP about your particular language(s) by filling a Feature Request using this [form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187181&template=1161183).

Comment: I was hoping you could manually add by saying period or comma at the appropriate time.